# Sent Wrapped ETH to contract address

Tags: wallets

I sent WETH to the contract address in Meta Mask wallet, any way of recovering this?
I went to the WETH page, but no way of contacting them there by the looks of it, and no socials.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this only. Person who deployed this contract can call the withdraw function if only this is been specified in the contract code.

Answer (score 0):

> I sent WETH to the contract address in Meta Mask wallet, any way of recovering this?

It's gone.